# Plotting trajectory with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a datafile with position of a moving point in the following format.

```
x1  y1
x2  y2 
x3  y3
.
.
.
```

I wish to make an animated trajectory with this data in gnuplot. How can I do that?

I tried

```
do for [i=1:20] {
plot "temp.dat" every ::i using 1 : 2 w p
}
```

But it plots all the points in a single image, not an animation. What is the way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I was coding and got interrupted... @Ethan's answer already contains all the necessary ingredients, I post my answer nevertheless, with a little visual demo...
Check `help gif`, `help stats` and `help every`, these are the main "components".
In the following example you hopefully find what you are looking for.

**Code:**

```
### trajectory animated
reset session

# create some test data
v = 40
a = 45
g = 9.81
set print $Data
    do for [i=0:86] {
        t = i/10.
        sx(t) = v*cos(a)*t
        sy(t) = v*sin(a)*t - 0.5*g*t**2 
        print sprintf("%.3f %.3f",sx(t),sy(t))
    }
set print

set xrange[0:200]
set yrange[0:80]

set term gif size 400,300 animate delay 5 optimize
set output "Trajectory.gif"

stats $Data nooutput
N = STATS_records
do for [i=0:N-1] {
    plot $Data u 1:2 every ::::i w l notitle, \
         '' u 1:2 every ::i::i w p pt 7 lc rgb "red" notitle
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the animation to show on the screen, then your code is fine except that you need to add a delay between the successive frames:

```
do for [i=1:20] {
    plot "temp.dat" every ::i using 1 : 2 w p
    pause 0.1   # 1/10 second between frames
}
```

If you are making an animated gif file then the pause doesn't go into the loop itself, it becomes a parameter to the `set term` command:

```
set term gif animate delay 10    # 10 = 10 units of 0.01 seconds
set output 'animation.gif'
do for [i=1:20] {
    plot "temp.dat" every ::i using 1 : 2 w p
}
```

Comment: The first part is not working actually. I am getting all points in a single plot instead of an animation.

Comment: The command you show is legal, but may not produce what you actually wanted.As written it should generate a plot starting at point 1, a plot starting at point 2, and so on. If  you want a single point per plot, maybe you want `every ::i::i` which says to start _and stop_ at point i.