# Radial animated plots

Tags: python, math, plot, data-visualization, gnuplot

I am quite amazed by [this radial animated visualization](https://www.koreus.com/video/nombre-quotidien-deces-france-2001-2020.html) (of daily number of deaths in France over years) by Baptiste Coulmont, and I would love to make my own plots of this kind.

[image: radial animated plot (screenshot)]

It seems the author produced it with R. **I wonder if this is feasible directly within gnuplot**, or if it requires programming in a general-purpose language.

Comment: How does your input data look like? Please show a data example...

Comment: It is just a time series with a given periodicity, so any format allowing to specify this is a priori ok. Hard-coding the periodicity is also a possibility (and then the data just comes as a time series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following could serve as starting point for a gnuplot implementation.
In order to animate check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61716971/7295599). There seems to an issues of clipping the polar graph when autoranging, i.e. `set rrange [0:*]`, which doesn't seem to be present when you set a fixed range, e.g. `set rrange [0:1000]`. There is certainly room for adaptions and improvements.

**Code:**

```
### radial animated plot
reset session

# create some random test data
# Gauss curve by specifing Amplitude A, position x0 and width via FWHM
GaussW(x,x0,A,FWHM) = A * exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*(FWHM/(2*sqrt(2*log(2))))**2))
myTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y"
StartDate = "01.01.2018"
EndDate   = "31.12.2020"
t0=int(strptime(myTimeFmt,StartDate))
t1=int(strptime(myTimeFmt,EndDate))
SecPerDay = 3600*24
set print $Data
    do for [t=t0:t1:SecPerDay] {
        Date = strftime(myTimeFmt,t)
        y0 = rand(0)*200+400
        y1(t) = GaussW(t,strptime(myTimeFmt,"01.02.2020"),100,SecPerDay*30)
        y2(t) = GaussW(t,strptime(myTimeFmt,"01.04.2020"),300,SecPerDay*10)
        y3(t) = GaussW(t,strptime(myTimeFmt,"10.10.2020"),400,SecPerDay*30)
        print sprintf("%s %g",Date,y0+y1(t)+y2(t)+y3(t))
    }
set print

DaysInMonth(t) = int(strftime("%d",strptime("%m.%Y",sprintf("%02d.%04d",tm_mon(t)+2,tm_year(t)))-1))
DateToAngle(t) = tm_mday(t)/DaysInMonth(t)*30 + tm_mon(t)*30
MonthToAngle(m) = (m-1)*30    # m=1 to 12

myDate(col) = DateToAngle(strptime(myTimeFmt,strcol(col)))
myColor(col) = tm_year(strptime(myTimeFmt,strcol(col)))

# extract the available years from data into table
set table $Legend
    unset polar
    plot $Data u (tm_year(strptime(myTimeFmt,strcol(1)))):(1) smooth freq
    set polar
unset table

set size ratio -1
set polar
set theta clockwise top
set angle degrees
set grid
set border 0 polar
unset raxis
unset xtics
set ttics 30
set format r ""
set rtics scale 0,0

# month labels
myMonth(i) = strftime("%b",i*SecPerDay*28)
do for [i=1:12] {
    set ttics add (myMonth(i) MonthToAngle(i))
}

set key at screen 0.95, screen 0.95 right
set rrange[0:1000]
set ytics 0,200 scale 0,0 nomirror offset -4,0
set rtics 200

plot $Data u (myDate(1)):2:(myColor(1)) w l lc var notitle, \
     for [i=5:|$Legend|-2] $Legend u (NaN):(NaN):1 every ::i-5::i-5 \
        w l lw 2 lc var ti sprintf("%s", word($Legend[i],1))
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Wonderful (both this post and the linked one), thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that this is helpful. It was also an interesting challenge for me. I learned again a few things. But keep in mind, people downvoted and wanted to close your question because they don't see your code and your own research effort. SO is not a "coding service".

Comment: Duly noted, you are right. Challenging a gnuplot expert was indeed my goal (as I thought is was not feasible purely within gnuplot). I just edited my question to this regard. In addition, I am sure that this code will be useful to many, including myself someday, so thanks again :)